# How to implement context menu with native GWT (Java)?

Tags: java, gwt, contextmenu

I'm new in GWT!
Can anyone help me to implement a context menu with GWT?
I have seen some example like:

```
MenuBar options = new MenuBar(true);
        MenuBar gwtPopup = new MenuBar(true);
        options.addItem("GWT", gwtPopup );
        MenuItem entryPoint = new MenuItem(new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscaped("EntryPoint").toSafeHtml());
        entryPoint.setScheduledCommand(new ScheduledCommand()
        {
            public void execute()
            {
                Window.alert( "hello" );
            }
        } );
        final DialogBox menuWrapper = new DialogBox( true );
        menuWrapper.add( options );
        gwtPopup.addItem( entryPoint );
        Button showMenu = new Button( "Click me", new ClickHandler()
        {
            public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
            {
                menuWrapper.showRelativeTo( menuWrapper );
            }
        } );

        RootPanel.get().add( showMenu );
```

but it doesn't works. Thanks.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What does not work? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: it will be good if you define which bit does not work in your code,   other thing is try to use PopupPanel instead dialog

Comment: Just blogged it for you  :)   http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/07/context-menu-or-right-click-handler-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Just blogged the steps to make it done with my working code for you.

[Context Menu or Right Click Handler in GWT](http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/07/context-menu-or-right-click-handler-in.html).

Here is the essential part of that code.

```
lable.sinkEvents(Event.ONCONTEXTMENU);
lable.addHandler(
    new ContextMenuHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            popupMenu.setPopupPosition(
                event.getNativeEvent().getClientX(),
                event.getNativeEvent().getClientY());
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    }, ContextMenuEvent.getType()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

event.getNativeEvent().getClientX() and event.getNativeEvent().getClientY() does not works well after scrolling the page.

Below is solution:

```
@Override
public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
    NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();

    // stop the browser from opening the context menu
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    int x = nativeEvent.getClientX() + getScrollLeft();
    int y = nativeEvent.getClientY() + getScrollTop();

    this.contextMenu.setPopupPosition(x, y);
    this.contextMenu.show();
}

public static native int getScrollTop() /*-{
return $doc.body.scrollTop;
}-*/;

public static native int getScrollLeft() /*-{
return $doc.body.scrollLeft;
}-*/;
```